# nullexception when trying to print value of object

Tags: java, io

So here i am taking records of chef name, city and value and storing it in obj and trying to store the values into a file.

```
Package yummy;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Chef
 {
   int value;
   String name;
   String city;   
 }

public class Yummy21 {    
 static Chef[] obj=new Chef[2];
 static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);    

public static void main(String args[])
{   
   Chef[] obj=init(); 
   //public static Chef init();
    PrintWriter     printer=createFile("C:\\Users\\Creative_Cimmons\\Documents\\content.docx");

    for(Chef exam : obj)
    {
      createOutput(printer,exam); 
    } 
}

public static Chef[] init()
{
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
    obj[i]=new Chef();
    System.out.println("for the object "+i+" enter the name ");
    obj[i].name=input.next();
    System.out.println("for the object "+i+" enter the city ");
    obj[i].city=input.next();
    System.out.println("for the object "+i+" enter the value ");
    obj[i].value=input.nextInt();
   }
return obj;
}
 public static PrintWriter createFile(String a)
 { 
     try
     { 
         File location=new File(a);
         PrintWriter printer=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new         FileWriter(location)));
        return printer;
     }       
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         System.out.println("I/O exception occured");
     }  
     return null;
 }

public static void createOutput(PrintWriter print,Chef exam )
{
    String holder=exam.name+" "+exam.city+" "+exam.value;   
    print.println(holder);               
}               
}
```

when i try to run it shows exception in createoutput(printer,exam). plz help

Thanks,

Comment: try change `for(int i=0;i<2;i++)` to `for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; ++i)` - your array has 3 elements while only 2 first are initialized

Comment: Post the exception please.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at yummy.Yummy21.init(Yummy21.java:72)
 at yummy.Yummy21.main(Yummy21.java:45)
Java Result: 1

Comment: sorry even though i changed to 2 it still shows exception!!! @kamil09875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj[i]` is null. Initialize it to `Chef` instance. You have just created an array which will contain objects of type `Chef`. But, you haven't actually created any instance of `Chef`. So, create a new Instance of `Chef` in the loop and assign the fields of it later

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    obj[i] = new Chef();
    System.out.println("for the object "+i+" enter the name ");
    obj[i].name=input.next();
    System.out.println("for the object "+i+" enter the city ");
    obj[i].city=input.next();
    System.out.println("for the object "+i+" enter the value ");
    obj[i].value=input.nextInt();
}
```

also change the filepointer to write onto to a .txt instead of .docx file

Comment: for the object 0 enter the name 
eff
for the object 0 enter the city 
dfdf
for the object 0 enter the value 
45
for the object 1 enter the name 
fgfg
for the object 1 enter the city 
ghgh
for the object 1 enter the value 
67
I/O exception occured
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at yummy.Yummy21.createOutput(Yummy21.java:109)
 at yummy.Yummy21.main(Yummy21.java:57)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17 seconds)

Comment: This seems to be the same `NullPointerException` in another line. Before it was thrown from `init()` method now it is `createOutput` method

Comment: yup same null exception when you call the method createOuptut(line 57 in main and when you go about implementing it(line 109) @Octopus

Comment: If you have corrected the code as i said in the answer, it should return an array of `Chef` instances, then the only candidate which can cause `NPE` is `print` Printer reference only. Check if it is `null`

Comment: changed as you told @Octopus , i am new to java programming and could you tell how the check must be implemented. Thanks a lot, really appreciate it!!!

Comment: In `createFile` method, after creating `PrintWriter` instance. Please add the code below `if(printer == null)` System.out.println("PrintWriter is null"); Do you see any message in console saying `I/O exception occured`?

Comment: it shows both IOException occurred and print is null

Comment: then, you are having problem in creating `PrintWriter`. Check whether it has write access to it

Comment: checked using cmd, yes the path is correct and checked the properties and yes it has permission to write just like any other docx file and my code is adapted from  http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/04/java-video-tutorial-32/

Comment: Try moving the file to someother drive other than `c:`

Comment: superb now no errors ( changed it to g:), you are almost there but the problem is that it is not gettin written onto the file

Comment: Try Adding `printer.flush();` after the `for` loop

Comment: Create a new file and test.. File gets corrupted when you play with o/p streams :)

Comment: thanx very much for your help, i feel you have helped a lot and now i need to relearn certain concepts on op/ip streams, if i find a solution i would mail u . Thank a lot,,really appreciate your help...

Comment: here is the problem, There is no need of `BufferedWriter`, just this will solve - `new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(location));`

Comment: ,, the reason bufferedwriter is given because everytime a character  is passed onto printwriter, printwriter invokes filewriter to write onto the file, so nothing wrong with bufferedwriter. Problem rectified, the problem is that i can use filewriter only for .txt files and not .docx files.. thanx a lot!!!

Comment: here is an explanation :- Microsoft Word's docx files are zip files with specific content inside them. Simply creating a file in Java and writing some text to them isn't going to create a valid docx file that Word will recognize, even if you give it a .docx extension.

To create them from Java you can use the Apache POI XWPF library. That will give you some Java classes that'll create and write contents to docx files that will work with Word.

Comment: @Creative_Cimmons Oh really, I was not aware of it. Can you please tell how you solved it?